# Why does `<Button Command={x:Static...}..>` works but `<Button Command={Binding...}..>` doesn't?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command

I'm new to WPF, and I'm trying to implement a custom `Command`, 
what I did is that I implemented the `ICommand` interface and I bound that implementation to a button using two ways one with a Static Extention Marckup
and one with a normal Binding, 
it works fine with `{x:Static}`, but fails with this error when using `{Binding}`

> System.Windows.Data Error: 39 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'StartCommand' property not found on 'object' ''ViewModel'
>   (HashCode=30880833)'. BindingExpression:Path=StartCommand;
>   DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=30880833); target element is 'Button'
>   (Name=''); target

here is my code

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="75" Width="300">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="30">
        <Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Content="Start" Margin="5,0"/>        
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel { Name = "Simple property" };
    }
}

class ViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // static to use with {x:Static}
    public ICommand StartCommand = new StartCommand();
}

class StartCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public event System.EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Start Executed");
    }
}
```

What's wrong with my code? am I messing something?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because

> You can make [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) references to static fields or properties

whilst field is not a valid [binding source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#binding_sources) and you need to convert it into property:

```
public ICommand StartCommand { get; set; }
```

and initialize it for example in costructructor

```
public ViewModel()
{
   StartCommand = new StartCommand();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I completely forgot that we can't use fields as a binding source